New Vs Update in Trigger Actions Framework Flow
We recently started using the Trigger Actions Framework for both our flows and triggers.
We have some flows that we need to execute for both updates and inserts. I can't find a way to check if the flow is being executed during an insert or update.
In an Autolaunch flow, we have a decision step to check conditions, but I can't use 'isNew' in that.
The only way I can see is to create a formula variable, but I can't use IsNew in formula variable.
In my record trigger flow I used to have below condition as entry criteria for both insert and update
((IsNew && record.Status != null) || isChanged(Status))

I can't find an equivalent condition in autolaunch flow.
Is there any easier way to identify both inserts and updates in autolaunch flow?

Does this answer your question? IsChanged Flow Entry Criteria when record is created

Thanks for using the Trigger Actions Framework!
When operating with the autolaunched flows in the framework, the indicator that you would use to determine insert vs update context would be if recordPrior is null or not.
Check out the documentation for the Flow variables within the project's readme:
https://github.com/mitchspano/apex-trigger-actions-framework?tab=readme-ov-file#define-a-flow
